# Is there a way to easily organise content in a Publishing site?

Tags: publishing-site, publishing-page, navigation

Does anyone know of a good solution for allowing a non-technical user to easily organise the content within a SharePoint publishing site?

I'm thinking of content that is organised into sections, subsections, and then finally pages.

A non-technical user should be able to simply see a map of all the sections, subsections and pages and easily organise that content:  e.g. to change the order of the sections, to change the order of the subsections, and to move pages between sections.  Ideally I'd want this to be nice AJAXy drag and drop, but failing that, does anything exist?

EDIT: my terminology is a bit confused I think, I'll try to explain better.  When I say sections, subsections, pages, I'm talking about organising the HTML pages in a website into some hierarchy.  So for example:

```
- Home
  -- Welcome
- Products
  -- Product A
     -- Product A Details
     -- Product A Image Gallery
     -- etc
  -- Product B
- Company
  -- About Us
  -- Corporate Policy
  -- etc
- etc
```

'Home', 'Products', 'Company', are sections.  'Product A', 'Product B' are subsections.  'Product A Details', 'Corporate Policy', etc, are pages.

So say someone wants to move 'About Us' from the Company section to the Home section, or they want the Product B section to come before the Product A section.  I guess what I'm asking for is a drag'n'drop site map, or something along those lines.

Comment: What do you mean by sections? For every site you get a pages library, a documents library, an images library. Isn't that enough? You can use the 'Manage content and structure' to move, copy, delete. Not AJAX though

Comment: Sorry, I think the terminology I'ved used is confusing.  I'm new to the SharePoint world.  I'll try and word it better in an edit to the original question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not particularly AJAXy, the "Manage Content and Structure" page, which is available for Publishing site collections, does allow you to create/delete/move sites and pages within your site collection.

[Manage Content and Structure 1 http://www.mossgeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/sharepoint2007.jpg](http://www.mossgeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/sharepoint2007.jpg)

[Manage Content and Structure 2 http://www.mossgeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/sharepoint4.jpg](http://www.mossgeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/sharepoint4.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Also you have hit upon a weakness in the WCM features in MOSS 2007 because you cannot have folders in a pages library.  The content would have to be oragnised using content types and page layouts.

However in SharePoint 2010 you CAN have folders in a pages library and furthermore you can use the Content Oragniser to automate the process of 'filing' your content so all your end users have to do is drop new pages into a drop-off library and SharePoint does the rest.  Cool stuff...

Comment: true for SP2007, but possible in SP2010

Comment: I like the idea of using the content organiser to route the pages, great idea!

Answer (score 1):

Metadata goes a long way in making this possible as well.  If you organize your content into a single library for each site, you can add column values (product a, product b, etc.)  This will allow users to utilize views to identify their content.  The bonus is that this also works toward improving your search results if you push those column values into managed properties.

Answer (score 0):

Pages are always created based on PageLayouts(A Template static in nature). So it cannot be dynamic in nature.

Comment: Sorry, I mean to dynamically alter the location of where a page is in the site structure.  Not to dynamically reorder the content of a page.